# Why is this relation not Symmetric

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

$R_1$ = {(2,2),(2,3),(2,4),(3,2),(3,3),(3,4)}

Is this not symmetric ONLY due to the ordered pair (2,4) not having symmetry with (3,4)? I can't seem to find a lot of information on how to deal with a relation being not a "property" and I'm not sure if my logic is right in how to deal with them (not symmetric, not transitive, not reflexive). Should I be looking for only one missing element?

Comment: symmetric means if x is related to y, then y is related to x. If (x,y) is in there, then (y,x) is in there. Well, (2,4) is in there but (4,2) is not, so it is not symmetric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Symmetry requires that if $\langle a,b\rangle\in R$, then $\langle b,a\rangle\in R$ as well. In this case there are two violations of symmetry: $\langle 2,4\rangle$ is in $R$ while $\langle 4,2\rangle$ is not, and $\langle 3,4\rangle$ is in $R$ while $\langle 4,3\rangle$ is not. These two violations are unrelated. It’s not that $\langle 2,4\rangle$ doesn’t ‘have symmetry with’ $\langle 3,4\rangle$: $R$ would still not be symmetric even if we removed $\langle 3,4\rangle$ from it, because it would still contain $\langle 2,4\rangle$ but not $\langle 4,2\rangle$.

To show that a relation does *not* have one of these properties you need only find one failure of the property. Here, for instance, the moment you find that $\langle 2,4\rangle\in R$ and $\langle 4,2\rangle\notin R$, you’ve shown that $R$ is not symmetric. You also know that $R$ is not reflexive: the ordered pair $\langle 3,4\rangle$ shows that $4$ is in the field of the relation, but the pair $\langle 4,4\rangle$ is not in $R$.

Comment: So then wouldn't this also be antisymmetric?

Comment: @jc707270: No, it’s not antisymmetric, because it contains both $\langle 3,2\rangle$ and $\langle 2,3\rangle$. An antisymmetric relation is one that never has both $\langle a,b\rangle$ and $\langle b,a\rangle$ unless $a$ and $b$ are actually the same element.

Comment: Ahhhh yes ok, forgot about that for a minute. Ok, thanks Brian

Comment: @jc707270: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 0):

To be symmetric, for every element (a,b) in R, (b,a) should also be in R. Hear (2,4) and (3,4) are not having their pairs in R. So R is not symmetric.